# Are there industry standards for incorporating a 10 MHz reference signal input into a design?

Tags: oscillator, reference

Are there any industry standards for accepting 10 MHz reference input signals into PCB designs? I've read about standard power levels (as in, 13 dBm at 50 ohm input impedance) in a few forums, but I'm not seeing more information about other best practices.

Specifically, I'm wondering how metering systems detect 10 MHz inputs and default back to internal references if they're not present.

Comment: I'm not aware of any universal standard here, but I would guess if there is, people probably followed HP/Agilent/Keysight specs and design.

Comment: Regarding how they default back, I think they are using a PLL to move their own oscillator to the right phase­.

Comment: @Julien, Thank you for your responses - I had similar thoughts for both. A PLL seems like it would be most useful because it allows signal detection and adjustment